# jquery inside an article

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a web application created in Joomla and I display an blog article after a menuitem is clicked. Do you know where can I insert the following code lines for the jquery to work out

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JPATH_SITE.’/media/system/js/jquery.js’ );
$document->addScriptDeclaration ( ‘jQuery.noConflict();’ );
```

The article isn't "created" with a module so I don't have a default.php file for me to insert the lines in. Do you know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Have haven't tried embedding jQuery in an article, but download [Direct PHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/4470) which allows you to write PHP code inside an article, then simply add your code. Don't forget to use the php tags.

If this doesn't work, you could always add the code to the index.php of you template.

Answer (score 0):

just put this in the head of your template index.php

`JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`

that will load jquery 1.8.1 (or so) in no conflict mode, the rest can go there, too...